# Sharing settings not making object private

Tags: sharing

I made a custom object private in Sharing Settings. When I log in as another user I can still see all of the objects. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Check the permission at profile level. If user have permission at profile level He/She can still view all records.

You might also need to check permission set.

Sharing Setting is used to give base level permission. It can't restrict access to object.

Comment: Yes. Removed View All and Modify All from profile. Thanks!